# Cannot deserialize custom Date object with Jackson in Springboot "no single-String constructor/factory method"

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Edit:

In an effort to clarify the issue I've made a diagram:

[image]

I've been migrating custom Jetty web services to use the Spring REST Templates and I've ran into an issue with the following deserializer.

The custom-date format comes back like so: `"2016-10-18"` and I need to transform that into 3 integers before calling a constructor of this custom `Date` type.

Previously this was working because we just passed the service an `ObjectMapper` with the deserializer registered and it called `deserialize` with no issues.

Now however I'm getting an error because Jackson attempts to call a `String` constructor on my custom `Date` type which doesn't exist. This library is not maintained by me and therefore I cannot add this constructor.

Error:

> "Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple
>   type, class com.intercorp.domain.date.Date] from String value
>   ('2016-09-30'); no single-String constructor/factory method

#### Note

Annotating the attribute that I am attempting to serialize works, but I do not consider this to be a solution because registering the deserialiser should detect the type and call itself. **I'm more interested in why this is not working than switching to annotations**:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=JacksonConfig.CustomDateDeserializer.class)
private Date paymentDate;
```

I have the following Spring config:

```
@Import({JacksonConfig.class})
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter;

    @Bean
    public MyWebService MyWebService () {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jacksonConverter);
        return new MyWebService(restTemplate);
    }
}
```

JacksonConfig.class

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        mapperBuilder.modules(myModule()).timeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
                     .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapperBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Module myModule() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("myModule", new Version(0, 0, 1, null));

        module.addSerializer(new CustomDateSerializer());
        //not Java Date - custom Date...
        module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new CustomDateDeserializer());

        return module;
    }

    // breakpoints indicate this is never called
    static public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

            @Override
            @SneakyThrows
            public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
                String text = jp.getText();
                if (text == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                if (text.length() >= 10) {
                    int year = parseInt(text.substring(0, 4));
                    int month = parseInt(text.substring(5, 7));
                    int day = parseInt(text.substring(8, 10));
                    return new Date(year, month, day);
                }
                // deserialize json object
                else if (JsonToken.START_OBJECT.equals(jp.getCurrentToken())) {
                    JsonNode dateNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
                    return getDate(dateNode);
                }
                else {
                    return new Date(Integer.parseInt(text));
                }
            }
        }

}
```

PaymentStatus.java

package com.otpp.memberapi.service.iaccess.data.pension;

```
import com.intercorp.domain.date.Date;
import com.intercorp.domain.money.Money;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PensionPaymentStatus {

    private boolean available;
    private Money netMonthly;
    //this date fails to deserialise
    private Date paymentDate;
    private boolean suspended;

}
```

Example JSON payload

```
{
    "available": true,
    "netMonthly": "1000.00",
    "paymentDate": "2016-10-19",
    "suspended": false
}
```

The date class is huge and just wraps Joda time (used in pre-Java8 envs). It has several constructors, the one I'm trying to use is a YYYY, MM, DD integer constructor.

Comment: difficult to understand without see more code but try at least to register the module to the object mapper, try to replace
"return mapperBuilder.build();" with   "ObjectMapper mapper = mapperBuilder.build(); mapper.registerModule(myModule()); return mapper;" and anyway it's nicer to resolve the dependencies of the beans passing the instances they need as parameters of the methods instead of calling the creation methods (e.g. objectMapper), I am not even sure if you are going to get the same instance in that way

Comment: Just one variable I forgot to rename. The module is registered in the builder `mapperBuilder.modules(myModule())`

Comment: Missed that because of the name, sorry :-), anyway ,,, try to resolve the dependencies passing the instances as parameters of the methods annotated with At.Bean to be sure that you are setting it in the correct beans, e.g. At.Bean public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) and so on

Comment: Tried that. Inspected the eventual `jacksonConvertor` injected to the `MyService` bean. All three `deserialisers` are present.

Comment: It may be useful to see a json and the model class you are using to map it

Comment: Added the wrapper model at the bottom of the question. The JSON value is in the error.

Comment: Can't you go with `java.util.Date` and later convert it to your `...intercorp....Date` ? OR validate it using a reg-exp or 'java.text.SimpleDateFormat' would be easy than having a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like request is not being deserialized by your converter.

RestTemplate`s no-arg constructor initializes it with default converters, relevant snippet:

```
....
if (jackson2Present) {
    this.messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
....
```

And since it uses 'first one wins' strategy to find appropriate converter it will never use yours because it is positioned later in the list.

You need to change:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jacksonConverter);
```

To something like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Collections.singletonList(jacksonConverter));
```

Depending on whether you need additional converters or not.

Comment: Only problem with this approach is that it attempts to use my deserialiser with every String if positioned before the String deserialiser.

I'm really looking for a solution that works with these date strings and regular strings. Maybe this can be done via regex? Example detect 8 digits in a string or just pass it off to the regular string deserialiser.

Comment: @Ash That does not seem right. Francly Im a bit confused, what String deserializer are you talking about? I dont see any in your question, and I do not observe such behaviour.

Comment: fyi basicaly Jackson determines what deserializer to use using target field`s type, so it should not use your deserializer<Date> for a String field.

Comment: To clarify if I put my Date deserialiser first it Jackson will attempt to run JSON strings through it. If I put it last then Jackson tries to use the standard String deserialiser. Like what it would use for the following JSON `{ myKey: "myStringValue}`but in my example it uses this against `{ myDate: "20161031"}`.

It's looking like there is no good solution because my data looks like a string...

Comment: _if I put my Date deserialiser first_ thats the most confusing part, you are not puting anything, beside your DateSerializer, anywhere in your snippets. Anywho, as I said before, Jackson uses property type (of your POJO) to select deserializer, it does not care what your date _looks_ like. Can you provide some info on how deserialization is invoked?

Comment: @Ash Any follow up regarding why my post doesnt answer your question?

Comment: Adding the Singleton of only my deserializers removes the existing ones. The result is that then Jackson isn't able to deserialize any standard objects that require no custom deserialization. I've tried this before but the default deserializers need to live alongside my custom ones.

`at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6f948a7f; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token`

Token is just a standard string in a plain JSON object. It now breaks. Works without.

Comment: Bounty awarded because what I wish to do does not appear possible in REST templates without annotations.

Comment: Although I still think this exception is unrelated, I'm 100% sure that what you want is not only possible but should be a default behaviour. And I would help if I could reproduce the exception, unfortunately you did not provide MCVE and I`m not familliar with RestTemplate to guess it. Try creating another question focusing your current issue.